# JMeter - Different Values of Latency for same Request Sample in different Listeners

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, latency

I've executed a single request for an API in Jmeter. When I am trying to check for the latency details, I get different values of latency in View Result Tree and View Results in Table.
Sample Details in View Results Tree Listener is Load time:23202, Latency:23202
Sample Detail in View Results in Table Listener is Sample Time: 23241, Latency: 0
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reNsW.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLimS.png)

What can be the possible reasons for the same?
Is there any way we can get the correct latency details in Jmeter when we hit any request?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the same is that you're looking into different results of the same.

If you open [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) using text editor of your choice or an application like [MS Excel](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/excel) you will see that there is one line for each request

And when you open .jtl results file using "Browse" button in the listener of your choice - the values are the same for each request in any listener

[image]

So the situation you're describing is not possible as you're comparing not the same results as they even have different response time.

More information:

- [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)
- [How Do I Run JMeter in Non-GUI Mode?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)